# my app stops working when i try to start on android studio

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a simple app with fingerprint but it stops working everytime I try running it.

Can you help me find what did I miss because i'm new to android studio and can't seem to know the problem and I searched a lot for it but nothing so far
here's the error

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.example.mohamed_pc.fingerprint, PID: 5215
>               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mohamed_pc.fingerprint/com.example.mohamed_pc.fingerprint.FingerPrintactivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>           ...
>           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
>           ...
>           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
>           ...
>           Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060054
>           ...

and here's my .xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mohamed_pc.fingerprint.FingerPrintactivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="176dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="112dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/finger" 
android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="161dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="108dp"
    android:text="@string/touch_sensor"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.457"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and that's my main class

```
   class FingerPrintactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "example_key";
    private FingerprintManager fingerprintManager;
    private KeyguardManager keyguardManager;
    private KeyStore keyStore;
    private KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
    private Cipher cipher;
    private FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject;
    protected void generateKey() {
        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
                    KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,
                    "AndroidKeyStore");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
                NoSuchProviderException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Failed to get KeyGenerator instance", e);
        }

        try {
            keyStore.load(null);
            keyGenerator.init(new
                    KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |
                            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(
                            KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                    .build());
            keyGenerator.generateKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
                InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
                | CertificateException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    public boolean cipherInit() {
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(
                    KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                            + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                            + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException |
                NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to get Cipher", e);
        }

        try {
            keyStore.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME,
                    null);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            return true;
        } catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException
                | UnrecoverableKeyException | IOException
                | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to init Cipher", e);
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fingerprint);
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
        if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {

            // This happens when no fingerprints are registered.
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Register at least one fingerprint in Settings",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        generateKey();

        if (cipherInit()) {
            cryptoObject =
                    new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
        }

        keyguardManager =
                (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        fingerprintManager =
                (FingerprintManager) getSystemService(FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);

        if (!keyguardManager.isKeyguardSecure()) {

            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Lock screen security not enabled in Settings",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Fingerprint authentication permission not enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return;
        }

        if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {

            // This happens when no fingerprints are registered.
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Register at least one fingerprint in Settings",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (cipherInit()) {
            cryptoObject = new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);

            FingerprintHandler helper = new FingerprintHandler(this);
            helper.startAuth(fingerprintManager, cryptoObject);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and that's a class that extends from the main

```
    public class FingerprintHandler extends
        FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {

    private CancellationSignal cancellationSignal;
    private Context appContext;

    public FingerprintHandler(Context context) {
        appContext = context;
    }
    public void startAuth(FingerprintManager manager, FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {

        cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(appContext,
                Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        manager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal, 0, this, null);
    }
    public void onAuthenticationError(int errMsgId,
                                      CharSequence errString) {
        Toast.makeText(appContext,
                "Authentication error\n" + errString,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpMsgId,
                                     CharSequence helpString) {
        Toast.makeText(appContext,
                "Authentication help\n" + helpString,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(appContext,
                "Authentication failed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
            FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {

        Toast.makeText(appContext,
                "Authentication succeeded.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **drawable/finger** is causing this error. I suggest you to use image loader library like **Glide/Universal Image Loader** to load images or decrease your image resolution size.

Comment: Try
1. without using image source..
2. create new xml file 
3. check if you have missed some files to keep in all drawable folders.